# Error magic number - Linux generated file R

Tags: r, format

I am receiving the error of

```
Error in load("~/Desktop/file") : 
bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘file’ has magic number 'column1'
Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I have tried loading it via `source()`, `load()`, and `readRDS()` - I tried this based off another help topic but it didn't aid my situation. It is a Unix generated file and I am aware Rstudio is not friendly towards unix.

My file contains tab-delimited data. Three columns.

Comment: Try read.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason the following read worked.

```
read.delim()
```